# Is implicit piece-wise function domain correct math?

Tags: functions

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle &\text{Let } {1/e}\leq{x}\leq{e}. \newline\newline &f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 && \text{if } x \leq 2 \\[1ex] 1-\frac{x}{4} && \text{if } 2<x\end{cases}\end{align}$$

is it false or even inaccurate to say that mathematically the function is technically implicitly defined as: $$f:[1/e,e]\mapsto[e^{-2},4]\,\cup\,(1/2,(1-e/4)]$$

Comment: If by implicit definition you simply mean a reference to the domain and codomain of the function, then your notation describing ‘$f$ maps this to this’ is all right.

Comment: What is implicit about this? You have specified exactly what $f$ does to each $x\in [e^{-1}, e]$.

Comment: Don't know about false, but this kind of notation is not common, at least. I would write it as $f :[e^{-1}, e]\to\mathbb R,\quad f(x) = \begin{cases}\ldots &,x\leqslant 2 \\ \ldots &, x>2\end{cases}$.

Comment: @AlvinL could it be that the OP is confusing the right side of the arrow as being the range instead of being the codomain?

Comment: No error in doing that though, after all the range is a subset of the codomain

Comment: thanks guys ! apparently my uni corrector has lost it, because they took away marks for apparently having "Slight inaccuracy in the domain. The function is only defined for x >= 1/e, this must be reflected in the piecewise function.", just because i didn't have the lower-bound restriction explicitly written as "1/e<=x<=2", even though it was explicitly mentioned by describing the domain of the indep. variable x earlier. thanks that clarifies it, i'll have a chat with them tomorrow. :P